# Detect if visual studio is running

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to detect if visual studio is running?
"#if debug / release" will just detect if a debugger is attached or not therefor if I run visual studio with "release" config that will not help.

For example, I would like to not use/call Azure Application Insights while running on a local environment. The following suggested code will do the job but only for debug runs. If a developer wanted to test its release configuration this will run and I don't want that.

```
#if !DEBUG
 .UseApplicationInsights()
#endif
```

just to be clear is there any built in variable / function to do something like this:

```
#if !local
  .UseApplicationInsights()
#endif
```

Comment: Can you update your question to provide more detail on why you want this done? The community may be able to provide alternate approaches.

Comment: Check running tasks and see if `devenv.exe` is in the list? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `#if debug` does _not_ check if the debugger is attached. It checks if the symbol `debug` is defined. These are two very different things. I believe what you're really trying to do _is_ actually check if the debugger is attached which you can do by checking the value of [`Debugger.IsAttached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_IsAttached).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the debugger is attached, if there is a .*NET* debugger attached to the currently executing code. If there is, it's reasonable to assume the code is running from the IDE.

[System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets a value that indicates whether a debugger is attached to the
> process.

Comment: if you run under "Release" configuration then the debugger is not attached, as far as I tested.

Comment: @Kamran then you have something else going on